# Why does Class.class.getResouceAsStream(String) always return null?

Tags: java

I tried to obtain a `.png` image from inside the classpath of my `.jar` file, so that wouldn't depend on a separate `resource` folder next to the `.jar`. I tried doing that with the help of the `Class.class.getResourceAsStream(String)` method. However, even after ensuring that the path to the `.png` image is valid, the method still returns `null`. The path to the file is:

```
source/org/linear/blank.png
```

The package also contains two additional files related to my project: the `Application` class and the `Console` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Class` class is loaded by the bootstrap classloader, and the Java documentation says that

> If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the method
>   delegates to `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`

And this method looks for resources in the `resources` folder.

So to make your code work you have two choices:

1)  Use one of your classes, for example, `Application`, instead of `Class`. In this case the resource path is resolved relatively to the location of the `Application` class:

```
Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/blank.png")
```

2) Put your image in the resources folder, in this case `getSystemResourceAsStream` will find it too:

```
Class.class.getResourceAsStream("/blank.png")
```